# GridDB server 4.6.0-1 for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: database, ubuntu, time-series, griddb

I am currently running Ubuntu 20.04 on my machine. GridDB's official web site's download page only shows GridDB CE(server)  for Ubuntu 18.04. Will I able to download (& install )?Will it support?

Answer (score 0):

After bunch of struggle and help from googling I managed to build v4.5 on ubuntu 20.04. So I would guess 4.6 will work too. I am running “arm” version which yet doesnt have source for v4.6.

Main problem was related to wrong version of gcc in v20.04 and so I had to download gcc 4.8 manually to build it.